# Biopython: genbank file by plasmid

Tags: python, bioinformatics, biopython, bios

So I want to make a genbank file in biopython , but I want it done by each plasmid in a cluster, as opposed to one big cluster  genbank file .  This is my code now :

```
  gbfile_name="test.gb"
  output_file = open(os.path.join("", gbfile_name), "w")
  SeqIO.write(record, output_file, 'genbank')
```

any ideas?

Comment: you should ask http://biostars.org

Comment: Can you add sample data?

Comment: You need to provide more information - where is the input data (i.e. ``record``) coming from? Also, your example as written can be shortened to ``SeqIO.write(record, "test.gb", "genbank")``